# Import blender textures on Unity 3D are always black

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, blender

I have the next simple Blender Texture:
[image]
[image]

This is a simple `png` file, imported to blender add added in the `Image Texture` component (at the left of the first image), with a transparent background.
I exported this texture in two format, the first one in `.blend` and the second one in `.fbx` format.

But, when I export this textures to blender (both formats) are a black rectangle and the spheres hasn't any texture, are totally gray.

What I'm doing wrong at the moment to import the textures?

[image]

Comment: well, the thing in the above blender screenshot isnt a texture, its a material. the texture is only the leftmost node (image texture). i guess the black comes from that in unity you didnt set your texture to use the alpha channel as transparency (just select the texture in the inspector, and tick "alpha is transparancy"). then you also need to set a material which knows how to deal with alpha channels. for standard this means you need to change the rendering mode to something different than opague

Comment: I don't think you can (at least last time i checked) import composite material from blender to Unity. You must try to recreate them as normal material and even so it will only import the color and the UVs. if you want a specific shader you have to try to recreate it with Unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to **bake** the material into **texture**.

I use **Maya** so I don't know the steps in Blender. You can google **Bake Materials in Blender**.When you bake the maps, you will get a Texture that is supported in Unity.

Usually, you create a simple flat plane, attach the material to the **plane**, position the camera in front of it, then **bake** it. For what you are doing, you only need the color map. You don't need normal maps and others.

Here are important links to learn that.

https://renderedsmoothie.wordpress.com/2013/09/05/baking-ambient-occlusion/

https://renderedsmoothie.wordpress.com/2013/08/31/how-to-bake-textures-and-materials/

https://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/bake.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tj-S5QAac3U

Comment: the above is only a transparent material with an image texture applied to a plane. theres nothing to bake there as the image already exists :D

Comment: @yes I don't know blender but in most 3D software,procedural images created in them are usually made in a format that only that 3D software can understand so that it can be easily modified later on. To get that image out, the receiver app will have to support it native or you have to bake it to a texture. If you have a complex material like in the picture above, you Must bake it to png,jpeg or other texture format supported in Unity or it will loose all those effects that was added to them in the 3D app, therefore resulting to something weird...

Comment: sure, and your answer as a general statement isnt wrong - its just, it is no complex/procedural material, its a "simple" image on the OPs picture (i think its called goal.png, but you cant read the whole filename). one of blenders renderers (cycles) uses a node based system, but its really only the setup for a transparent texture.

Comment: @yes "theres nothing to bake there as the image already exists" No. That's **not** just an  image texture, he applied other effects to it such as Translucent and then mixed the shader with **Mix Shader** before the output. If that was a simple **Diffuse Material**, Unity would support it. It becomes a complex material once you start connecting different materials,shader effects or nodes  with each. If all he did was to connect the png file to a simple **Diffuse Material**, that would have worked in Unity.

Comment: i see, that was a misundestanding on my part then. and maybe its just me - since getting my materials from blender to unity doesnt work without fixing everything up manually anyway - i usually create my materials in unity by hand right away.

Comment: @yes It should work when you have 1 shader only. If you mix it with anything else, it won't and it should not work.So you bake with multiple materials. That's why we have **bake** in GD. Creating materials by hand when you have 5 gameobject is fine. If you work in a team and you have over 1000 3D objects, doing it by hand will waste your company's time and that's a pain. I don't know for blender but Maya has a way to bake everything in order. You select all models and hit bake then go to bed. All 3D models materials will be converted into 1 texture and 1 material and unity supports that.

Comment: i also batch bake my texturemaps (not in blender though), then import everything to unity and assign the maps to their corresponding slots of the material/shader i want. having each individual texturemap on the same texture would require multiple uv layouts (but i wonder if we aint talking about the same things and our terminology just doesnt match - or well, mine probably ^^) the above thing is more like you create materials in UE4.

Comment: @yes When I said bake all maps, I meant to to say that Maya will automatically create 1 material and 1 texture for **each** 3D model and plug **each** baked Texture to **each** material so that you won't have to do this  manually in Unity. After baking, whatever it looks like in the scene, is what it will look like in Unity. It does not combine all the 3D textures together. It combines **all** textures of **1** 3D model to just **1** texture. That thing you do manually is what Maya does for you. I think we are talking about the-same thing. What software do you to make and bake your 3D models?

Comment: blender for modeling, xnormal and photoshop for textures. im no artist though, the only reason i know and do all this, is because i have noone doing it for me and i also think its kinda mandatory to be familiar with the process if you intend to create games - i mean how could i if i dont undestand what a normal map is or even where models get their fancy colors from? i come from a different background though, more the coding side.

Comment: @yes. Yeah it's good to know at-least basic 3D stuff even when you are just a programmer. I use Maya and V-ray. Model with Maya, do HQ texture bake with V-ray in Maya then import whole scene in Unity. IT works without modifying anything. If after baking and there something is wrong, I fix it with Photoshop.  Happy coding!